# In a linked list, in what order are nodes removed by the destructor?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

In a linked list, in what order are nodes removed by the destructor?

Does it go first to last or last to first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either order is possible -- the only way to be certain is to inspect the specific implementation you're using.

In general, for a singly-linked list, I would expect a first-to-last ordering because it's easier to implement and a bit more efficient:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node *node = mHead;
    while (node) {
        Node *next = node->mNext;
        delete node;
        node = next;
    }
}
```

Versus a last-to-first ordering, which for a singly-linked list will generally require some sort of recursion:

```
void deleteList(Node *node)
{
    if (node == 0) {
       return;
    }
    deleteList(node->mNext);
    delete node;
    return;
}
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
   deleteList(mHead);
}
```

So again -- the only way to be sure is to look at your linked list implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that since the compiler reads code. From up to down   the destructor deletes from first to last.  you can even use { }|   to ensure the re allocation of memory before it will usually happen.